# Why are folders in desktop opening with a wrong file manager?

Tags: 18.04, nautilus, kde, filemanager, dolphin

I use Ubuntu 18.04. I installed KDE DE for a while. But now when I boot into to gnome (default Ubuntu DE), I see all the folders in desktop just open with Dolphin FM, and not with Nautilus!
I have tried to check the Default File manager with the code below-

```
xdg-mime query default inode/directory
```

and the result was Nautilus!

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Mixing the two may be problematic since there isn't a good separation between the mime databases and the X Desktop Group (XDG) standards also complicate things a bit. You can likely fix this specific problem by going into KDE and running the File Associations tool and changing `inode/directory` to use Nautilus by default, however, this will also obviously cause directories in KDE to open using Nautilus.